# How to add content and moreDetailsUrl for Google Search suggest?

Tags: google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I'm using GSA (version 6.14) and we would like to get an auto suggest function on our website. Works fine for basic requests, but it seems the GSA offers more functionality when you would be using user-added results. However, I can find nowhere a reference on how to add user-added results.

This is what the information tells me today :

```
/suggest?q=<query>&max=<num>&site=<collection>&client=<frontend>&access=p&format=rich
```

should return a response as below :

```
{
"query": "<query>",
"results": [
{ "name": "<term 1>", "type": "suggest"},
{ "name": "<term 2>", "type": "suggest"},
{ "name": "<term 3>", "type": "uar", "content": "Title of UAR",
"moreDetailsUrl": "URL of UAR"}

]
}
```

I am able to get results as the first 2 lines, but would like to get results as the last line also, so with content and a moreDetailsUrl. So maybe a very stupid question but I am not able to find the answer anywhere : How and where do I add this UAR ?

I actually want to understand if it's feasible to get metadata into the content part of the JSON, so if for instance an icon meta is available I'd like to have it included in the JSON so I can enrich my search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Added Results are a OneBox that can be added to multiple frontends.  See this: https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/614/admin_searchexp/ce_improving_search#uar

When done with Suggest, the data is fed from user entering 'keymatches' directly.  What's different about them is that they are a direct link versus a suggested query.  If you use the out of the box experience, you'll click a link to the url instead of running another query.